# How to combine 3 different font files as one ttf file?

Tags: html, fonts, truetype, html-rendering, fontforge

I need to use font forge to combine three separate font files, such as Heuristica, Sourceserif, and Timesnewroman into a single ttf file.

I tried this by keeping one of the font files as the base file and copy pasting the glyphs from the other font files to generate a single custom TTF file. Rendering to HTML using the generated TTF file causes glyph height differences

Comment: Different Font designs have different metrics, proportions, stem widths etc. You would need to manually adjust glyphs to get e.g,  "normalized"  capital- and x-heights. If you dive into type design - you can do this, but it will take a lot of effort to get a seamless result.

Comment: Working with font files and glyphs looks like it might be better suited for the folks at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). I'd recommend the tags `fonts` and `truetype-fonts` over there, as well.

Comment: The real question is: "why?" Because there is no reason to do this. Use three separate fonts, with appropriate `@font-face` CSS rules for each, and CSS classes that ensure the same general typeface dimensions.